# AngularJS ng-show ternary conditional with multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs

Im working on a complex app where I need to disable a link if the ID sent from backend meets a certain criteria.
I'm using this now but not sure if it is correct:

```
ng-show="parentheaderData.casid === '807' || '806' || '808' ?false:true"
```

Does this look right?

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you move this logic to a controller so you have

html :

```
ng-show="showParentheader(parentheaderData.casid)"
```

controller:

```
 $scope.showParentheader = function(id) {
     return  ! (id === '807' || id ==='806' || id ==='808');
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for all the support. The correct solution was:

```
ng-hide="parentheaderData.casid == '806' || parentheaderData.casid == '807' || parentheaderData.casid == '808'"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
ng-show="(parentheaderData.casid === '807' || parentheaderData.casid ==='806' parentheaderData.casid === || '808') ? false : true"
```

or:

```
ng-show=" !(parentheaderData.casid === '807' || parentheaderData.casid ==='806' parentheaderData.casid === || '808')"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-show="(parentheaderData.casid === '807' || parentheaderData.casid ==='806' parentheaderData.casid === || '808') ? false : true"
```